# Can I get money from both insurance companies because of a damage in parking lot?

Tags: united-states, insurance, car-insurance

Few days ago I noticed a damage on my car's body that was parked in my parking spot. There was a paper on the car that "Sorry for this happened, please call to talk about the insurance ...".

As my car has it's own insurance coverage that covers damages that happens while my car is parked, I want to know can I make a claim on my own car insurance and get compensation from both my, and the beater's insurance?

May somebody explains the whole process in more details? This is the first time this happens to me and I don't know anyone to ask.

Comment: Generally your insurance will ask you if you have insurance details of the other party, and will ask them to reimburse.

Comment: @littleadv: May you explain the whole process in more details? This is the first time this happens to me and I don't know anyone to ask.

Comment: You should ask your insurance agent. Generally if you have the details of the party at fault, your insurance will work with that party on reimbursement. Only if you don't know who caused the damage your insurance will cover it (and then it will be technically treated as a claim against your insurance).

Comment: What is going to happen is that your insurance will ask if the other guy had insurance and try to figure out who is to blame. Then they will call the insurance company, and fight over who pays. If either finds the other has already paid they will deny your claim

Comment: JohnFX, it’s usually not really a “fight”. Insurance companies have lots of claims in either direction, the cheapest is if they just pay up. Now if one insurance company had a reputation of taking money but refusing to pay out (to other insurance companies) that would be very bad for their business. Because nobody would cooperate with them anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you should make one, and only one, claim with your own insurance company.

You can't make a duplicate claim, but you should be "made whole" after the two insurance companies work together. If your insurance policy requires a deductible for the damage claim, and if the other party is 100% at fault, then you shouldn't have to pay that deductible. Or you should be reimbursed after paying that deductible.

> Basically, subrogation is when one insurer (e.g. American Family)
> receives money from another insurer (e.g. the at-fault driver’s
> insurance company) so that the not-at-fault driver gets their
> deductible back.

https://www.amfam.com/resources/articles/understanding-insurance/auto-deductible-not-at-fault-accident